# magento template debuing suddenly appeared

Tags: php, magento

I'm a beginner magento developer.

I know this sounds stupid but for some reason my magento system started to have a life of its own.

it entered to template debug mode so i checked my control panel and saw it was on yes when the check box "Use Website" was checked (which i don't know what it means), so i unchecked it and picked no.

all the debug boxes disappeared but one.
which i don't understand where it comes from.

here is my site : http://www.bellaterracosmetics.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your show template path hints and show block path hints are on

Goto System >> Configuration

Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that

will allow you to turn on/off template path/block path hints.

Goto system >> Cache Management Clear and refresh all cache :)

Comment: Thank you very much clearing the cache solved the problem. can you explain what does the cache is good for?

Comment: @user2312281 the cache is good to speed up the website